# Display Arabic content in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing app for window phone 7 .I call one service that return me xml. This xml contain Arabic as well as English content. I can read English content but for Arabic character output look like this ?????????.
I want to display both Arabic and English content in my app please help me

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Segoe WP family of fonts I have on my computer (*which I got by installing the WP7.5 dev tools*), the font doesn't contain Arabic characters. This is why you're seeing question marks.

So, seems like you need to use some other available font which contains Arabic characters or embed your own entirely. [See this link for a list of available fonts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/10/supported-fonts-on-ie-for-windows-phone-7.aspx), the editor is a bit weird in the sense that it allows you to use any font even though there's just a limited set of fonts available.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following post may help you:

[Indic language display](http://roboshashi.blogspot.in/2012/02/indic-langauge-display-in-wp7.html)